# Google Gmail Contextual Gadget Example

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets, google-caja

So I'm interested in learning how to program a Gmail gadget to do some silly things but I have no experience in it.  I have spent the past month or so sporadically reading through the API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets), but haven't made much progress.  I was wondering if anyone with experience would be willing to answer the following:

1) What files exactly do we need for a gadget?  Just the manifest and the spec? Should they have specific names?

2) https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?csw=1#hello_world_example_manifest   Where this link has the example code and says to substitute your own info in for *example.com*, what does that mean?  And why do we need to do this?

3) Would you have some really simple gadget, i.e. a 'hello world' that you would be willing to share as an example?  (I'm not trying to steal your code, I'm just interested in seeing a full finished piece and seeing what I need to work on in my project)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

For creating a gadget you need minimum of 2 files.

`manifest.xml` - specifies extractor and gadget

`gadget.xml` - it includes what you would like to display in mail

Check [this guide](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/04/28/google-contextual-gadgets-gmail/) for more details.

Comment: So where it talks about deploying the gadget, it says that we can sign into the console with: http://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/mydomain.com     
If I don't have a domain to use, is there a way to deploy and/or test?   Thanks!

Comment: @Chewy did you find a way to do  it ? Their lack of documentation is very annoying !